# Tkinterにて，ボタンが押されるまで次の処理を待機する方法を教えてください．

Tags: python, selenium, tkinter

TkinterとSeleniumを使ったアプリケーションで，スタートを押すとChromeが起動し，スタートを押すと
`input('>何かを入力すると，コンソールにp要素のテキストを表示')`
が動作し，コンソールでエンターキーなりを押すまでp要素の取得を待ちます．
次に
`input('>何かを入力すると，コンソールにh2要素のテキストを表示')`
が動作し，同じくh2要素の取得を待ちます．

このような動作の「コンソールでエンターキーなりを押す」を「次へボタンを押す」に対応させて，次へボタンを押すまで次の処理を待つといった処理を行いたいのですが，どのように実装すればよいでしょうか．

処理を止めたい理由は，出力を一つずつ，目視で確認した後に，次の処理へ進むようにしたいためです．

現状，next()は何も行いませんが，本来は次へボタンを押すとnext()が動作し，次の処理へ進めればと思っています．

処理１
next()が実行されるまで待つ
処理2
next()が実行されるまで待つ
処理3
︙

ご教示くださいませ．

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

```
import time
import ctypes
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

try:
    ctypes.windll.shcore.SetProcessDpiAwareness(True)
except BaseException:
    pass


def next():
    pass


def start():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    )
    driver.get('https://scrape-b276b.web.app/')
    input('>何かを入力すると，コンソールにp要素のテキストを表示')
    print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#app > div > main > div > div > div > div > section > div.text > p').text)
    input('>何かを入力すると，コンソールにh2要素のテキストを表示')
    print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'h2').text)
    input('>何かを入力すると，終了')


def main():
    frame = tk.Tk()
    frame.title('title')
    frame.geometry("230x60+400+440")

    button1 = ttk.Button(frame, text='次へ', command=next)
    button1.place(x=10, y=10, width=100)
    button2 = ttk.Button(frame, text='スタート', command=start)
    button2.place(x=120, y=10, width=100)

    frame.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: ちなみに、何故コンソールから入力する必要があるのでしょう？ 入力はtkinterのEntryウィジェットで、実行用にボタンを追加して、出力だけコンソールにすれば難しいことは要らないのでは？

Comment: ありがとうございます。処理を止める方法としてinput()を用いただけです、本当は次はボタンを押すと次の処理へ進めるようにしたいです。ですので、Entryウィジェットも不要かと思うのですが。

Comment: その「処理を止める」必要があるのは何故なのか？「次のボタンを押して次の処理へ進める」(今はnext()は何もしていませんよね)といった事の詳細を質問記事に追記してみてください。

Comment: 求めていらっしゃる回答になっているかわかりませんが，追記しました．

Answer (score 2):

[XY問題](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2701)ですね。

おそらく「スタート」ボタンの処理が終了すると`webdriver.Chrome(...)`で開始したブラウザのウインドウが終了してしまう状況を止めてウインドウを表示したままにしたいのだと思われます。

その原因は`def start():`関数の中で`driver`オブジェクトを作成していることです。

関数の中で作成したオブジェクトはローカル変数の扱いになり、グローバル変数に代入するとかしなければ、関数が終了すれば破棄されます。
あらかじめ`def start():`関数の外で`driver`オブジェクトを作成しておけば待機する処理などは不要で問題は解決するでしょう。

以下のようにしてみてください。関連する部分だけを抜き出して記述します。
next()の呼び出し確認

```
def next():
    print('next()呼び出しの確認。')
```

start()のサイト表示処理(input()等は削除しておく)

```
def start():
    driver.get('https://scrape-b276b.web.app/')
    print('start()呼び出しの確認。')
```

あらかじめdriverオブジェクトを作成しておく

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
    )
    main()
    driver.close()
```

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございました．